# Remove double quotes from the Json_encode result

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I'm trying to fatch some data frm database, and trying to create a new json file. However, in my output I'm getting double quotes in the array.

I tried many solutions available on Stack Overflow but no success so far. Help me remove it.

```
   $to=array("name" => "Today","data" => $count1);
   $yes=array("name" => "Yesterday","data" => $count2);
   $ab=array($to,$yes);
   $y=array("format" => "percent");
   $z=array("labels" => $ti);

  $json=json_encode(array("series" => $ab,"y_axis" => $y,"x_axis" => $z));

     $fp = fopen('data.json', 'w');
      fwrite($fp, $json);
     fclose($fp);
```

Current output:

```
{
    "series": [
        {
             "name":"Today","data":["123","123","123"]
        }
    ],
    "y_axis": {
        "format":"percent"
    },
    "x_axis": {
        "labels": ["00:00","00:00","00:00"]
    }
}
```

I don't need double quotes around 123 & 00:00.

Comment: If you want integers, you should cast them to integers before you add them to the `$countX` array. And `00:00` is not a valid number, so the only way to store that in json, is as a string.

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve the issue? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

For no values use `floatval($var);` Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Current output:

```
{"series":[{"name":"Today","data":["123","123","123"]}], "y_axis":{"format":"percent"},"x_axis":{"labels":["00:00","00:00","00:00"]}}
```

Handle `"123","123","123"` using `floatval($var);`
 and `["00:00","00:00","00:00"]` will come in double quotes as its strings.

Comment: Hi Fakruddin adding "floatval($var);" worked perfectly fine.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @DhruveePatel my pleasure helping you. Let me know if you require any further help.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting all the integer values to integer (you can cast to float with the `floatval()` function):

```
$to=array("name" => "Today","data" => (int)$count1);
```

EDIT:
I have missed that the `$count1` is an array. You can cast all the elements of the array to integer.

```
function castArrayOfStingsToArrayOfIntegers(&$array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $var) {
        $array[$key] = (int)$var;
    }
}

castArrayOfStingsToArrayOfIntegers($count1)
```

You can use any other way to traverse the elements. Consider that it will have minimalistic performance impact if you have a lot of values in the array. You should think if you really need this values as integers and if this is the correct place to cast them. It can be better to cast them while you are constructing the `$count1` and other similar arrays.

SECOND EDIT:
If you have a lot of items keep in mind that the cast using `(int)` is a lot faster(around 2 times) than the `intval(`) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to convert your `$count1` variable to integer as follows:

`$to = array("name" => "Today","data" => array_map('intval',$count1));`

**[Proof of concept]**

```
<?php

$count1 = array("1","2","00:00","10");


$to = array("name" => "Today","data" => array_map('intval',$count1));
var_dump($to);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "Today"
  ["data"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(0)
    [3]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
```